# Save and send cookie after HTTP request

Tags: ios, swift, cookies

I'm login through an API using a POST request with `URLRequest` and `URLSession`. Everything seems to work well since I receive the correct response from the API.

Then I want to send a GET request to the same API but it seems that I'm not connected anymore.

For what I saw, the API is sending a Cookie in its Header in that form :

`Cookie:PHPSESSID=abc123`

I guess the problem is coming from that cookie wich is not send when I do a GET Request.

Here is my code.

ViewController :

```
    @IBAction func Connection(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let loginFunc = Login()
    loginFunc.login(username: username.text!, password: password.text!) { jsonString in
           let response = jsonString
           print(response)
    }
    let get = GetRequest()
    get.get(req: "patient/info") { jsonString in
        let response = jsonString
        print(response)
    }
}
```

Login.swift :

```
    class Login {
    func login(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://myurl/web/app_dev.php/login_check")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let postString = "_username=" + username + "&_password=" + password
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        var responseString = ""
        let mysession = URLSession.init(configuration: config)
        let task = mysession.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let field = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Cookie"]
            print(field)
            print(type(of: response))
            completion(responseString)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
  }
```

GetRequest.swift :

```
    class GetRequest {
    func get(req: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://myurl/web/app_dev.php/" + req)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        var responseString = ""
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            print(responseString)
            completion(responseString)
        }
    task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you app terminates, the session cookie will be not saved as it's a session cookie

Comment: What do you mean ? It does not terminate, I'm sending the get request right after

Comment: Strange, try this session config then ?
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.httpCookieAcceptPolicy = .always

Answer (score -2):

Hey for sending cookies along with your ajax request please use. You need to use withCredentials to true.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});
```

Comment: That's swift3 not ajax ?

Comment: hey sorry, you can use the same concept. :)